# ¿Como puedo solucionar este error en fedora 39 a la hora de correr postgresql?

Tags: linux, postgresql, fedora

Dice que para Fedora no se recomienda postgresql 16, mas bien el 15, pero ya lo intente hasta con el 13 y me sigue mandando esto...

```
# *Job for postgresql-13.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
# See "systemctl status postgresql-13.service" and "journalctl -xeu postgresql-13.service" for details.***
# *
```

...y según yo he seguido todas las instrucciones.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Falta mucha información relevante en tu pregunta, ¿que pasos concretos has seguido para instalar?¿La [documentación de Fedora](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/es/quick-docs/postgresql/#installation)? El error (que supongo que es de systemctl) solo nos dice que el proceso termino de forma inesperada, ¿cual es la salida de systemctl status y qué te muestra journal (los comandos que el propio error te invita a usar)?

Comment: La causa puede ser muy variada, desde no haber inicializado correctamente la bd, no existencia o problemas de acceso a los directorios de la misma, incluidos permisos/usuario propietario incorrectos, configuración de seguridad incorrecta, errores en el propio .service...

Comment: y que dice la salida de lo que te indica? `journalctl -xeu postgresql-13.service`